# Is it possible check value in switch for being object?

Tags: php, object, switch-statement

I have some array like this:

```
$array = array(
    'one' => 'value_one',
    'two' => 'value_two',
    'three' => 'value_three',
    'four' => array(
        '1' => 'one',
        '2' => 'two'
    )
);
```

And i am running it in foreach loop and for each value i am running other code.

```
foreach($array as $key=>$value)
{
    switch($value)
    {
        case 'value_one':
            // some code;
            break;
        case 'value_two':
            // some code;
            break;
        case 'value_three':
            // some code;
            break;
    }
}
```

I am wondering is there a way to check the last one to being array or an stdClass Object?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: [is_array](http://php.net/manual/en/function.is-array.php), [is_object](http://php.net/manual/en/function.is-object.php), [get_class](http://php.net/manual/en/function.get-class.php), ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not directly. You could find ways to fit (nest) everything into that `switch` statement, but really that would serve no practical purpose and only end up in bad code being written.

It would be better to switch to an `if` statement instead:

```
if ($value === 'value_one') {
}
else if ($value === 'value_two') {
}
else if ($value === 'value_three') {
}
else if (is_array($value)) {
}
else if ($value instanceof stdClass) {
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [`is_object()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.is-object.php) and [`is_array()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.is-array.php).

Like so

```
if (is_object($value)) {
    // do something
} elseif (is_array($value)) {
    // do something
} else {
    // error
}
```

Comment: You mean like this: case is_object(): ?

Comment: Gave an example, if you must use `switch` then just put it under the appropriate switch condition.

Answer (score 0):

You can take advantage of the `default` case like this:

```
switch($value)
{
    case 'value_one':
        // some code;
        break;
    case 'value_two':
        // some code;
        break;
    case 'value_three':
        // some code;
        break;
    default:
        if(is_array($value)) {
           //some code for array here...
        }
}
```